# Skip downloading dash manafest

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I am trying to use youtube-dl to crawl youtube.  My goal is to have it find the thumbnail for the url and return that.  Not sure if downloading the dash is necessary.

Here is what I have so far, but it still shows "Downloading dash manafest"

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl


class MyLogger(object):
    def debug(self, msg):
        print msg
        pass

    def warning(self, msg):
        print msg
        pass

    def error(self, msg):
        print(msg)


def my_hook(d):
    if d['status'] == 'finished':
        print('Done downloading, now converting ...')


ydl_opts = {
    'list_thumbnails:': True,
    '--youtube-skip-dash-manifest':True,
    'logger': MyLogger(),
    'progress_hooks': [my_hook],
}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.extract_info('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc',  download=False, process=False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct option is `'youtube_include_dash_manifest': False`.